# Being יוצא with the chazzan saying - ה' אלוקיכם אמת, if I am not up to Kerias Shema yet

Tags: halacha, chazzan-prayer-leader, shema, motzi-yedei-chovato

Kerias Shema consists of only 245 words. In order to say 248 words in , the chazzan repeats the words "ה' אלוקיכם אמת". If one davens without a minyan one should say "אל מלך נאמן" in order to reach 248 words. [משנה ברורה, או"ח ס"א, ס"ק ו.](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.61.6?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

Hearing the words from the chazzan works with the concept of שומע כעונה. What is the halacha if a yachid is not up to where the chazzan is and as such, hears the chazzan saying ה' אלוקיכם אמת while the yachid is still in a different section of davening, for example פסוקי דזמרא?

Does the yachid have to say אל מלך נאמן upon reaching shema or can he rely on the chazzan, even though the yachid heard ה' אלוקיכם אמת while he was still in an unrelated section of davening?

Also, does it make a difference if the yachid heard the chazzan saying ה' אלוקיכם אמת while the yachid was saying Kerias shema vs. an unrelated section of davening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would seem that both questions can be answered at once.

The Shaare Teshuva on that Halacha that listening to the 3 words from the Chazzan may be done even if you are in middle of krias shema yourself:

> וכתב בסדר היום מי שלא השלים ק"ש וכבר הקדים הש"ץ וסיים יותר טוב שיעמוד במקום שהוא וישתוק וישמע לש"ץ כשחוזר ה' אלקיכם אמת ואח"כ יגמור הק"ש ויועיל לו כיון שהוא עומד בתוך ק"ש וזה עדיף טפי מלכוון בט"ו וו"ין ע"ש

Rav Chaim Kanievski in Ishei Yisroel Teshuva 46 states that this Halacha of the Shaare Teshuva is only for during Shema and not anywhere else in davening.

The Sefer Hachaim from R Shlomo Kluger (siman 3) says that it would also work if one was finished the bracha but did not say the first word of Shema yet.